# Bigdata SQL Server 2008 hadoop

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

How to get aggregate info from the SQL Server using hadoop. I'm using windows server 64bit machine.

Comment: if you are asking about loading the data from RDBMS to Hadoop, then you can use sqoop

Comment: Thank you can you suggest any tutorial site??

Comment: you can go through http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html, if you want something more then google is your friend